# Display a gif image after submitting a input text in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, gif

Write a javascript program that will ask to input a text. 
Press `submit` button to display gif image of that named text.

Suppose the input text is *243*, after pressing submit button then it will display *243.gif image*.

> **Input:** 243
>   **Output:** 243.gif image

Comment: I guess it your HW, if you have any attempts please show the code.  So that we can help you

Answer (score 0):

**Nope**, it is not possible to generate a gif image *with only Javascript.*

You need some server side coding/ plugins where passing the number returns the gif image(which can be handled via **`ajax`**).

Answer (score 0):

As Praveen stated in his answer, you will need to use a combination of a server-side language and JavaScript. Something like PHP can process your input text like so:

```
<?  
    $text = $_POST['input_text'];
    $file_name = time().'-'.$_POST['input_text'].'.gif';
    $im = @imagecreate(110, 20);
    $background = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    $text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

    header("Content-Type: image/gif");
    imagestring($im, 5, 5, 5,  $text, $text_color);
    imagegif($im, $file_name);
    imagedestroy($im);

    echo $file_name;
?>
```

Your HTML will look something like this:

```
<img id="img" src="">

<input type="text" id="input_text">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
```

If you're using jQuery then you can use something like this to ajax the image after it's been processed:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var image_text = $("#input_text").val();

    $.post('ajax.php', { input_text: image_text }, function(data) {
        $('#img').attr('src', data);
    });
});
```